# How to align an image at middle of wrapped text

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to wrap an image with some adjacent text, and i can align it to **top-left and top-right** using `align=""` attribute or `float`. But how can i align image to the **vertical and horizontal center** of whole text after wrapping.

Like this:

[image: This is how it should look]

I have tried below code,

```
<p>
<img align="middle" src="http://placehold.it/140x100" /> Some More text Here....
</p>
```

Comment: Is it ok if in the solution which i provide you cannot select the background text?

Comment: I think we do not have such property in HTML or css.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/yCSeE/) for the image shown in the question:

**CSS:**

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#main{
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.class1{
    position:absolute;
}
#child1{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:justify;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png);
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
}
```

---

### Solution 2

If you want to ***wrap the text around*** the only way to do it is using float.See this [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/s3uq4/)

**CSS**:

```
.class1 img{
    float:left;
}
```

---

### Solution 3

But the above solution will not allow you to center the image.For centering image you will have to do
some trick like this [Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/RBzva/) . But this will require large amount of effort to adjust writing between the two columns/divs.

Comment: Sorry, even if i demo image shows little overlapping with text i never meant it, the text should wrap around the image

Comment: but float will not align the image to middle.

Comment: @PrasanthKC You will have to use the third solution if you want to get the output you asked for.

Comment: @PrasanthKC did you see the fiddle in the third solution

Comment: And you cannot get vertical centering for what you asked. I think its impossible to obtain with html and css.

Comment: 10 points in 7 years. You earned 'em. I was wondering about this just now.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it with a single block of text (I can't think of a single instance where it's aesthetically pleasing and functionally desirable, but I'd love to be proved wrong), but you can with two columns. There's a great article on it here:

http://alistapart.com/article/crosscolumn

Essentially, you use pseudo-elements to create an empty space that is the same size as the image, then position the image onto that space.

Comment: It may have taken 7 years, but you deserve those 10 points.